# MySQLi execute not returning false on function failure

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a function to insert into a table, then insert into another with `LAST_INSERT_ID` and finally return the `LAST_INSERT_ID`. It works fine except that there is a `foreign key` that can make the function fail error 1452. This happens when I test with a bad foreign key in `MySQLWorkbench` with this query:

```
SELECT create_match(1,2);
```

However in `PHP`, if the function fails it still returns true.

```
    $query = "SELECT create_match(?,?)";
    if (!$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query))
        error_log("CreateMatch() Failed to prepare statement: " . $this->mysqli->error . __FILE__ . " Line: " . __LINE__,0);
    else {
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $gameID, $userID);
        $success = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($res);
        $stmt->fetch();
    }
```

`$success` is true even if the function failed. Why might this be and how can I detect if the function failed? I am weary about testing it in the function because I am returning an unsigned int and any number could be valid.

Comment: If you execute the function from php, then do you get the results you expect from the function, or you do not get anything back **and** there is no sql error raised either?

Comment: I get a 0 back but I am not sure if this is a false or a null being evaluated as an integer. But either way, a zero is not expected.

Comment: It is possible that the 2 mysql connections (workbench vs php) have different settings, therefore what raises an error in workbench, only raises a warning in php. Can you pls execute the function with incorrect parameters and then run a show warnings **from the php code** and output its results?

Comment: what do you get from [mysqli::$errno & mysqli::$error -- Returns a string description of the last error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) when it fails?